# Using a File to Output Arrays and Tables

Tags: java, arrays

so I have a problem: Write a program to read each student’s name and raw score from a file by calling a method “readData()” and store this information into two parallel arrays “names” and “scores”.

I'm so stumped as to how to do this, the rest of the problem not listed here is easy but i can't do this. the text file that it read from is in this format:

```
Name1    80
Name 2   56
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you need help with homework problems, you need to show some effort.  SO is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: It's unclear where your stuck, but you might like to start with [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).  You will also get a better response if you first make some effort to solve your own problems.  Start by simplifying the problem, you first need to be able to read the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo code :

```
 In LOOP till file ends
    read file
    Read every line as string
    Use .split() method to seperate them as individual token
    Store name in String array and Other one in Integer array
 LOOP close
```

end

Eg.

`put a exact tab space in file betweeb name and score. go to file after name press tab button and delete extra spaces`

```
 File file = new File("yourfilename.txt");   
 String[] names = new String[50]; 
 int[] scores = new int[100]; 
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
 l = 0;

/*Core logic*/
 while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { 
 String line = scanner.nextLine();
 String [] words = line.split("\t"); 
 names[l] = words[0]; 
 scores[l] = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
 System.out.println(" name: " + names[l] + ", score: " + scores[l]);
 l++; 
  }
```

You can implement readData() method with this sample code now

Comment: I didn't write java code since it's your homework.. Hope this helps @JustAJAVAGUY

Comment: Which loop do i use and when I used the split method, I thought I had to create two different arrays because there are two lines and two different strings.

Comment: Just create two different arrays initially ..after . Split store one in string array and other one in integr array and increment the index...

Comment: my code needs some work but i dont know what to fix.

Comment: Check my edit @JustAJAVAGUY hope this helps.. Accept the solution if it does

Comment: Thank you,  i just didn't get the parseint while i was working but now i understand what needed to be done :)

Comment: Gud @JustAJAVAGUY ..parseint converts string to integer since ur word array is string