# Using a txt document into parallel arrays

Tags: java, arrays, parallel-processing, stringtokenizer

My problem is:Write a program to read each student’s name and raw score from a file by calling a method “readData()” and store this information into two parallel arrays “names” and “scores”.  So ive been stumped as to how to actually separate characters and put them int their respective arrays.Here is what i have:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ReadData 
       {
         static void readData() throws FileNotFoundException 
            {

    File file = new File("data.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    ArrayList<String> Names = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    ArrayList<String> testScores = new ArrayList<String>();

    int i = 1;
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scanner.nextLine();   
        switch(i)
        {
        case 1: Names.add(line);i++;
        String [] Names1 = line.split("\t");
        System.out.println(Names);
        break;
        case 2: testScores.add(line);i++;
        break;           
        }

        if(i >= 7){i=1;}
    }

    System.out.println(Names.toString());
    System.out.println(testScores.toString());

    scanner.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: how is this different to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627592/using-a-file-to-output-arrays-and-tables ?

Comment: I have seen this question before.

Comment: i have added my code

Comment: i just need some guidance as to how to get it into the arrays if im even supposed to do that

Comment: You still haven't explained what exactly you're stuck on.

Comment: alright so when i run this program i get [ name 65]

Comment: but i need them to be organized into parallel arrays

Comment: you are adding the entire line to your Lists, try splitting first and adding just the relevant part.  Also I have **no** idea what you are doing with the `switch` and the `i` variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a File to Output Arrays and Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627592/using-a-file-to-output-arrays-and-tables)